# Debug Flash socket

Tags: sockets, flash, websocket, flashdevelop

So modern browsers have built in tools to see what is going on in the background. Wether there's, for example, a websocket connection or a long polling one you can actually debug it in real time, in a production environment, in real circumstances. It's so useful that it's become mandatory for most programmers. You can debug everything out of the box, but Flash sockets.

So how to debug Flash sockets? I've seen there's only an extension for Firefox but they ask me a lot of money to try it, and that won't happen. How come there isn't an open source alternative? Is it because Flash is dying?

Comment: I think the answer is because Flash in the browser is a proprietary tool from one vendor that is being phased out and is not even supported on mobile.  One might ask why you're using a Flash socket instead of a webSocket (which has built-in debugging tools in all browsers).

Comment: Your Flash app is running via a plugin in the browser, you cannot expect it to compete with the browser itself (a native app which is directly communicating with the OS & its network functions). WebSockets are handled by your browser and web scripts (JS etc) can access the feedback. A plugin app is not meant for [doing] that. Just imagine as... it exists on 2 or 3 layers away from the information you seek. I'll elaborate in an answer later on...

Comment: I was gunna elaborate but it just occured to me... **Have you even tried** to write code to process received/sent messages via sockets? Give me an example of some debug information you require but your AS3 code could extract? Show the code and maybe it can be fixed. If you need an example try **[this code](https://github.com/theturtle32/AS3WebSocket)** for a hint, if you have not even started...